# What kind of proof of residency is accepted by Disneyland?

Tags: paperwork, covid-19, residency, disney

Disneyland is set to reopen on April 30th [for California residents](https://disneyland.disney.go.com/experience-updates/):

> Until further notice, only California residents may visit the parks, and in groups no larger than 3 households, in line with current state guidelines. **Proof of residency may be required.**

What kind of proof will be acceptable for entry? I've tried searching around their website but couldn't get more specific information. Obviously a drivers license should work but is anything else acceptable?

Comment: Did you ask them?

Comment: @DJClayworth I did email them, haven't got a response yet. Will post an answer when (or if) they do get back to me.

Comment: Driver's license, passport, or passport ID card. What do you have and why do you think it may be a problem ?

Comment: @Hilmar US passports don’t prove residency in a particular state. I’m asking because someone I know wants to go but they haven’t gotten around to changing their drivers license yet due to DMV being a mess.

Comment: @JonathanReez more than that, US passports don't prove anything about residence whatsoever.  In New York, official proof of address can include utility bills, bank statements, other account statements, other pieces of mail, and property records (lease, deed, tax records, etc.), but I have no idea what Disneyland would accept.

Comment: On [this page](https://disneyland.disney.go.com/offers-discounts/southern-california-tickets/details/), it states that the credit card must have a socal address and a government-issued photo ID is required.

Comment: @mkennedy yes I’ve seen that page but it talks about a different ID requirement.

Comment: Where does it say they ask for proof? They are reproducing the State guidelines for social activities. They also say a valid ticket is required for those aged 3 or over. Do visitors bring the birth certificate for the under-threes?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Finally received an official response from Disney's email support:

> A Government-issued photo I.D. (such as a driver's license or state I.D.) or any documentation that has the Guests name and a California address will work as proof of residency.

Also, [according to a Reddit comment](https://www.reddit.com/r/Disneyland/comments/mvmji2/explain_like_im_goofy_disneyland_resort_reopening/gwfvsxz/?utm_source=reddit&utm_medium=web2x&context=3):

> I have heard several people confirm that today they were NOT CHECKING IDs. That could change but they were not today.

So in practice you might not get checked, at least for now.

Comment: That can change any moment. I would not trust on it. Better bring the best proof you can think of.